# gnome-terminal error

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

In my `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` file, I have this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 109, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 99, in main
mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
NameError: name 'GLib' is not defined
```

Do you know how to solve it please? I believe this is the reason why I cannot start `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: is it just by trying to start `gnome-terminal` or with a python code? if it's the 1rst case, where did Ubuntu prompt you this error?

Comment: Have you modified something in `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`? What is the output of `grep "from gi.repository import GLib, Gio" /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`?

Comment: If you haven't customized anything I would use `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal` before investing alot of time.

Comment: Please add to your question "glib" at the end, specifying the error

Comment: The output is [from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
]

Comment: 'from gi.repository import GLib, Gio'

Answer (score 1):

Your `gnome-terminal` program (Python Script) is corrupted. Here's some quick checks:

```python
$ wc /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

 107  213 3368 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

$ tail /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

    GnomeTerminal(sys.argv[:], mainloop)

    try:
        mainloop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Word count program (`wc`) tells us it is 107 lines, 213 words and 3368 characters.
- Tail program (`tail`) shows what the last 10 lines look like.

In your case an accident/bug caused part of `gnome-terminal` to be overwritten with garbage. Although we could spend time trying to figure out what caused the problem, it is easiest just reinstalling. Assuming there are no custom modifications done to `gnome-terminal` then:

- Open console login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
- Log into the console with your User ID and Password.
- Type `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal`.
- For Ubuntu 16.04 return to your GUI desktop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
- For Ubuntu 18.04+ return to your GUI desktop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: I did the sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal. Unfortunately it did not work out

Comment: Did you run `tail  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal` before and after reinstalling to confirm it was corrupted before and changed after?

Comment: the tail gives me this output :

Comment: GnomeTerminal(sys.argv[:], mainloop)

    try:
        mainloop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()